# No audio device detected for an Asus X206H netbook under ubuntu 16,04, what should I do?

Tags: drivers, sound, 16.04, asus, intel

I just bought an Asus X206H netbook and installed a 16,04 ubuntu. The main problem is that I can't get any sound out of it. Apparently it doesn't detect any audio device

Here's what lspci -v returns :

```
ioo@ioo-E200HA:~$ lspci -v
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 2280 (rev 22)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 10b0
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Kernel driver in use: iosf_mbi_pci

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 22b0 (rev 22) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 10b0
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 311
    Memory at 90000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at 80000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

00:0b.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 22dc (rev 22)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 10b0
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 312
    Memory at 91639000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: proc_thermal
    Kernel modules: processor_thermal_device

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 22b5 (rev 22) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 10b0
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 116
    Memory at 91600000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Device 2298 (rev 22)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 10b0
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 313
    Memory at 91500000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Memory at 91400000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: mei_txe
    Kernel modules: mei_txe

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 22c8 (rev 22) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 115
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: 91200000-913fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 229c (rev 22)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 10b0
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
    Kernel modules: lpc_ich

01:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros Device 0042 (rev 30)
    Subsystem: AzureWave Device 2b31
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 314
    Memory at 91200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
```

Also, in the system parameters -> sound, it says "Play sound through : Fictive output" (maybe it's not the exact translation sorry)

What should I do to fix this issue?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

There is no sound at the moment because of some I2C issues, the drivers of the backtrail cpu are necessary to get the realtec soundchip running. You can follow this thread, the drivers of the X205TA should be the same and the guys there are working very hard to get that sound out of that bunch of hardware.
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2254322&page=123

EDIT:
Sorry its not the same one, but Pierre Bossart informed the community that intel will release a working codec driver soon, so be tuned :)
https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=115531#c18

Answer (score 0):

They did a great job and created a easy script to get the sound running on your x206h: https://github.com/Grippentech/Asus-E200HA-Linux-Post-Install-Script

Thanks to Takashi, Pierre-Louis, and Grippentech, awesome work!